# Representing population variables in a map

Tags: cartography

Could some one advise me in some ways (or popular ways) of representing population variables in a map? For population variables I refer to: distribution of age among the population, people with elementary school, etc..

Comment: What make you think there is a best way? Cratography is more of an art than science, and Population has been shown in various ways. Have you studied/researched some maps which show this data, before you asked this question?

Comment: I understand your point, and you are right. The wording of the question is wrong... I am asking for some pointers... I am new of this. could you point me to some places for see the maps which you are refering?

Comment: I modify the wording of the question

Comment: I am so sorry but I think this is a duplicate question of [Effectively displaying demographic data on a printed map] How I can close this question?

Comment: You can just click on the 'delete' link below your question (just below the cartography tag)

Comment: @Devdatta Although few would deny the artistic elements of cartography, it nevertheless has objective *principles* informed by its claim to represent data or to approximate reality. Also stemming from this are perceptual principles that apply to cartography and not to most other visual arts.

Comment: @whuber: While I don't deny your point, When Someone asks "which is the best way to show something cartographically", I feel that it cannot be answered in an objective way.

Comment: @Devdatta I agree with that but would qualify it with "but it is possible objectively to determine that certain ways are better than certain other ones for certain purposes."